# Dense Rank in Unsorted Arrays (Clickhouse)

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way I can get the dense rank for the elements in the (unsorted) array.

For e.g. if I have an array [100,200,50] --> I need the relative rank of these elements from highest to lowest e.g. output -> [2,1,3]

Tried thinking about how to use arrayEnumerateDense but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, can be used the function [arrayEnumerateDense](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#arrayenumeratedense-arr). It is applied to reverse sorted array to get the required ranks and then map them to origin array.

```sql
SELECT
    [100, 200, 50, 200, 50] AS arr,
    arrayReverseSort(arr) AS sorted_arr,
    arrayEnumerateDense(sorted_arr) AS sorted_arr_dense,
    arrayMap(x -> (sorted_arr_dense[indexOf(sorted_arr, x)]), arr) AS arr_dense
FORMAT Vertical

/* Result

Row 1:
──────
arr:              [100,200,50,200,50]
sorted_arr:       [200,200,100,50,50]
sorted_arr_dense: [1,1,2,3,3]
arr_dense:        [2,1,3,1,3]
*/
```

The same result can be got without using arrayEnumerateDense:

```sql
SELECT
    [100, 200, 50, 200, 50] AS arr,
    arrayReverseSort(arrayDistinct(arr)) AS sorted_dist_arr,
    arrayMap(x -> indexOf(sorted_dist_arr, x), arr) AS arr_dense
FORMAT Vertical

/* Result
Row 1:
──────
arr:             [100,200,50,200,50]
sorted_dist_arr: [200,100,50]
arr_dense:       [2,1,3,1,3]
*/
```

Comment: BTW, use `arrayMap(x -> indexOf(sorted_arr, x), arr) AS arr_dense2` to get rank which caluculate same element in ranking which is `[3,1,4,1,4]`